# Scalar Potential (Proof for Singularities)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a problem with the scalar potential. At the moment, I'm working with electromagnetism (Maxwell theory) and there's a vector field $w$ with $\vec{\nabla}\times w=0$, for which one can find a scalar potential. I know that a curl-free field implies the existence of a potential function and I have a proof for the case that $\nabla \times (\cdot) = 0$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, as can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638099/why-curl-free-field-implies-existence-of-potential-function).

My question is how can you prove you can find a potential function if there is a singularity in the vector field? For example, my vector field $w(x)$ is defined for all $x \ne x_0$ and has a singularity at $x_0$.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks. but $\mathbb{R}^3$ isn't simply connected...i have given: $w(x) = \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|^3} (x-x_0)$

Comment: @lissy1234567 $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ **is** simply connected because you can shrink every closed loop into a point.

Comment: sorry, i meant R^3 \0 isn't simply connected, like you told in your first comment:)

Answer (score 3):

**You can't, because in general this is false.**

Lets look for example at the following vector field

$$\vec{F}=\left(-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}},\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}},0\right) \tag{1}$$

that is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus\{\left(0,0,0\right)\}$. It is easy to see that

$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}=\begin{vmatrix}\hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z}\\\partial_{x}&\partial_{y}&\partial_{z}\\-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}&\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}&0\end{vmatrix}=\hat{z}\left(\partial_{x}\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\partial_{y}\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)=\hat{z}\left(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-2x^{2}}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-2y^{2}}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)=\vec{0} \tag{2}$$

So you might think that there exists a potential function $V$ such that $\vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla}V$, but this would imply that

$$\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{{\rm d}\ell}=0 \tag{3}$$

for every closed curve $C$. If we choose $C$ to be the unit circle in the $\rm XY$ plane, namely

$$\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\right),\:\: \theta\in\left[0,2\pi\right) \tag{4}$$

then

$$\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{{\rm d}\ell}=\int_{C}\left(-\frac{y{\rm d}x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{x{\rm d}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\sin^{2}\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta+\sin^2\theta}+\frac{\cos^{2}\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta+\sin^2\theta}\right){\rm d}\theta=2\pi\tag{5}$$

which clearly contradicts Eq. $3$, and therefore a potential function does not exist. This fact is related to objects known as *[differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form)*. The vector field in Eq. $1$ corresponds to the differential form

$$\omega=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\rm d}x+\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\rm d}y \tag{6}$$

and the fact that $\vec{F}$ is curl-free (Eq. $2$) is equivalent to saying that the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) of the form vanishes

$${\rm d}\omega=0 \tag{7}$$

Such a form that satisfies Eq. $7$ is called *[closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms)*. The existence of potential, in the jargon of differential forms, is written as

$$\omega={\rm d}\alpha\tag{8}$$

and one then refers to $\omega$ as an *[exact form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms)*. It is always true that an exact form is closed, but the opposite is false as you've seen above. Nevertheless, if one assumes that the domain in question is a *[star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain)*
 (note that one may require an alternative condition), then the statement is iff. In the example we studied the domain is $\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus\{\left(0,0,0\right)\}$, and it is obiously not a star domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, but if there's a star domain given. How can i proof it?

Comment: @lissy1234567 You should take the star point of your domain and define your potential function at $x$ as the line integral of the field on the straight path connecting the star and $x$. Then you should show that this is indeed a potential function by calculating the gradient.

Comment: thank you for your help!