# Topology, true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> a) $\forall j : R^2 \to R^2$  $C^1$ function, $\exists k : R^2 \to R$ : $\nabla k(x) = j(x)$
>
> b) $R^n$ has only one open vector subspace
>
> c) $R^n$ has several compact vector subspace
>
> d) Let $h : R^2 \to R$ a continuous function and $A$ a compact of $R$, $h^{-1} (A)$ is a compact

I did not manage to answer these questions satisfactorily

for b) i said "true" because if there is an open vector subspace, this open vector subspace is $R^n$

c) A compact is a bounded closed space, i said "true" but i'm not sure, i said that there are several singleton

d) I said "true" because $h^{-1} : A \to R^2$  a continuous function so $h^{-1}(A)$ is a compact

I don't know how to answer for a)

Thank you

Comment: how to do you that $h^{-1}$ exists?  say $h: (x,y) \mapsto \sin(x)$ has a compact range $[-1,1]$ for a sufficiently large open circular disk on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

For b), subspaces are closed, and not open, except $\Bbb R^n$ considered as a subspace of itself, which is both open and closed. Kevin's answer, now deleted, had an argument with hyperplanes, another almost equivalent one: subspaces are defined by linear equations. The preimage of $\{(0,0,\dots,0)\}$ by a continuous function is closed.

For c), all subspaces are unbounded, except the null subspace.

For d), use my comment for b) to find a counterexample: the preimage is closed, but not necessarily compact ($h^{−1}$ is not a function!)

---

For a), the curl of the gradient is always zero. So it's not always possible to find a potential $k$ for a given vector field $j$. However, if $\mathrm{curl}\; j=0$ (i.e., the vector field is conservative), then such a $k$ exists. See [Why curl free field implies existence of potential function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638099/why-curl-free-field-implies-existence-of-potential-function) In two dimensions you have to consider the scalar curl.

To find a counterexample, it's thus enough to find a vector field $j(x,y)$ such that $\dfrac{\partial j_1}{\partial y}\ne \dfrac{\partial j_2}{\partial x}$.

Let $j$ be the linear map:

$$j(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}$$

That is, $j_1(x,y)=y$ and $j_2(x,y)=-x$.

Then, a potential $k$ for this vector field must satisfy:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x}&=&j_1(x,y)&=&y\\
\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial y}&=&j_2(x,y)&=&-x
\end{eqnarray}$$

From the first equation, you get that $k(x,y)=xy+a(y)$, for some function $a$ of only $y$. But then

$$\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial y}=x+a'(y)$$

And since $a'(y)$ does not depend on $x$, there is no way this can be equal to $-x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! For a) we did not introduce the notion of curl in our course i think they want us to find a counterexample by brute force

Comment: @Kurapika I added a counterexample.